# IONIC 4 tab navigation

Tags: tabs, ionic4

I am using IONIC 4, I faced an issue in using . In my application I have 4 tabs and in each tabs we have a sub page. On navigating to 1st tab and we have a link to load sub-page, once we load the sub page and go to another page by clicking 2nd tab, after that when we agin click the first tab then it is showing the sub page at first time, and when we again click on the first tab then it loads the main page.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button [ngClass]=" activated === 1 ? 'selescted': '' " (click)="activateTab(1)">
      <ion-label>Teams</ion-label>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="activated === 1" src="../../assets/svg/team-active.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="activated !== 1" src="../../assets/svg/team.svg"></ion-icon>

    </ion-tab-button>
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code where your error occurs...

Comment: Please show code and names of the pages so we can understand the routing you are mentioning

Comment: <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button [ngClass]=" activated === 1 ? 'selescted': '' " (click)="activateTab(1)">
      <ion-label>Teams</ion-label>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="activated === 1" src="../../assets/svg/team-active.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="activated !== 1" src="../../assets/svg/team.svg"></ion-icon>

    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>